How to add Differences between all levels of different stratas in gtsummary
I am trying to create a table where I can see the % of cases for a number of variables, by Gender and year, and add to that a "Differences section" between year and gender.
Here a simplified reprex with a single variable. This is the table to which I want to add a Differences section.
library(gtsummary)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(tidyr)


# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------

Data2017 = structure(
  list(MyVARIABLE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Sí", "No"), label = "SPSS label 1", class = "factor"), 
       Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Mujer", "Hombre"), class = "factor")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Data2023 = structure(
  list(MyVARIABLE = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Sí", "No"), label = "SPSS label 1", class = "factor"), 
       Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Mujer", "Hombre"), class = "factor")),
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



# Initial table ----------------------------------------------------

final_data =
  Data2017 |> mutate(year = 2017) |> 
  bind_rows(Data2023|> mutate(year = 2023))

# Keep label
attr(final_data$MyVARIABLE, "label") =  attr(Data2017$MyVARIABLE, "label")

initial_table = final_data |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = year,
    ~.x |> 
      gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = Gender, statistic = gtsummary::all_categorical() ~ "{p}%") |>
      gtsummary::add_overall() |> 
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
  )

initial_table


Final goal
My final goal is to have a section of the table where the differences between years appear for each value of Gender (plus the overall). A very nice plus would be to have some statistical test telling me the p-value for that change...

My hack
My very bad hack is to use the gtsummary table to get the differences, but I don't know how to append this to the right of the initial table... and of course, this needs to work when there are multiple variables (think SPSS label 2, etc.)
# Calculate differences for each value, between years ---------------------

Table_DIFFS_years = initial_table$table_body |> 
  mutate(var_type_3 = "categorical",
         stat_0_3  = ifelse(grepl("%", stat_0_2), readr::parse_number(stat_0_2) - readr::parse_number(stat_0_1), ""),
         stat_1_3 = ifelse(grepl("%", stat_0_2), readr::parse_number(stat_1_2) - readr::parse_number(stat_1_1), ""),
         stat_2_3 = ifelse(grepl("%", stat_0_2), readr::parse_number(stat_2_2) - readr::parse_number(stat_2_1), "")
  ) |> 
  drop_na() |> 
  select(label,  stat_0_3, stat_1_3, stat_2_3) |> 
  rename(Overall_DIFF = stat_0_3,
         Mujer_DIFF = stat_1_3,
         Hombre_DIFF = stat_2_3)

Table_DIFFS_years
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   label Overall_DIFF Mujer_DIFF Hombre_DIFF
#>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 Sí    -20          -53        4          
#> 2 No    20           53         -4

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!
Created on 2024-07-26 with reprex v2.1.1
